# Setting a color for click event on a d3 map

Tags: jquery, svg, onclick, d3.js

I currently have counties in my map highlighting and removing the highlight on mouseover and mouseout. I would like to set a separate color for a click event - this would mean that the selected county would stay this new color until a new county is clicked independent of any mouseover or mouseout event. I currently have the color of the county changing on click, but only when the mouse is over the element.

Here's what I currently have:

```
        .call(d3.helper.tooltip()
          .text(function(d){ return 'County: '+ newDict[d.id][0] + '<br />HOPE Dollars: $' +commasFormatter(newDict[d.id][1]); }))
          .on('mouseover', function(d){ d3.select(this).style({fill: '#FAAE0A', stroke: '#F08C00', opacity:'0.5', 'stroke-width':'3px'}); })
          .on('mouseout', function(d){ d3.select(this).style({fill: '', stroke: '', opacity:'1', 'stroke-width':''}); })
        .on("click", function(d) {
        $('#nameCounty').html(''+ newDict[d.id][0] +'')
        d3.select(this).style({fill: '#F08C00', stroke: '', opacity:'1', 'stroke-width':''});
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Of course you have to hover over the element to click it. The only way to separate this is to have another element trigger the click on it so you don't have to mouseover it.

Comment: I want the clicked item to stay highlighted until a new item is clicked. I know that how I have it set up right now is not correct. If I do set up the trigger separately, though, how would I get the clicked item to reset on a new click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to "un-highlight" an item when another one has been clicked, you need a way to find the previously highlighted item and unset its "highlighted" status.

One way to do this is to assign a particular `class` to the highlighted item that allows you to find it again later. Whether you use that to also set the style of the item doesn't matter.

For example, on a `click` the following would first find the previously highlighted item by searching for an item that has the `.highlighted` class, remove the `.highlighted` class from that item, and then assign the `.highlighted` class to the current item:

```
.on("click", function () {
            // Find previously selected, unselect
            d3.select(".selected").classed("selected", false);

            // Select current item
            d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);
        });
```

You can try it out in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXB2p/).

Comment: Couldn't get it to work in mine quite yet, but I'll keep working on it and let you know. Thanks for the fiddle.